# Checking several arrays for null in an if statement

Tags: c#, if-statement

Is there a better (nicer) way to write this if statement?

```
Array a =null, b= null, c= null, d= null;
if(a!=null && b!=null && c!=null && d!=null)
{ //// TODO }
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that is the most minimalistic way you could write that. You could probably create a function that checks if all parameters are null, but what is the point to that because this seems to run perfectly as is.

Comment: Some places i have 9-10 array to check for null, it make the if condition very clumsy. So wanted to check if there is any better way to do this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can make an adhoc collection and then perform a Linq All query on it:

```
if(!(new [] {a, b, c, d}).Any(_ => _ == null)) {
    Console.WriteLine("None of the arrays are null");
}
```

Try it out [here](https://dotnetfiddle.net/SKOlVG).

**EDIT:** I just saw your comment. It looks like you want to use this in a lot of places with varying sizes, so you could do something like this:

```
static bool areNoneNull(params object[] things) {
    return !things.Any(_ => _ == null);
}

public static void Main(String[] args) {
    if(areNoneNull(a, b, c, d)) {
        /* Do stuff */
    }

    if(areNoneNull(x, y)) {
        /* Do different stuff */
    }
}
```

Comment: Solution is nice, probably you might consider using `Any` for this case `things.Any(_ => _== null)`, we don't really require to verify all items if we found one is not _null  _.

Comment: thanks, this what i was looking for. Had one more question performance wise which one will be better (if condition or linq). tried to make changes in fiddle but it is showing almost same for both the cases

Comment: You're right; I misread the logic when I wrote the solution, so I switched over the equivalence check rather than the function. I'll correct that.

Comment: @Yogesh - performance around function calls shouldn't be something you worry about in a managed language like C#; code clarity and reuse is far more important. Hari Prasad's point about `Any` is correct though; it's unlikely to impact any performance test much at all, but it will be an efficiency improvement at no cost to clarity, so it's worthwhile.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a list of array for this scenario: that is :

```
Array a =null, b= null, c= null, d= null;
List<Array> listArray = new List<Array>() { a, b, c, d};
if (listArray.Any(x => x == null))
{
    // array contains null value
}
else { 
// do something
}
```

Comment: it will work but i don't to create a variable and then check as it will use unnecessary memory.